# How to document external file in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, ini

I've found a lot of questions about documenting an .ini file.
I've also read the special commands of doxygen. http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbinclude

For me it is still unclear how to structure the file that I get the sections, 
name of variable, unit, range, default value and description.
It is totally fine for me to create a file which I only use to document this .ini file. (e.g. inidocumentation.h) but I wasn't able to manage the sections and make sure that it doesn't mix with the other documented classes and so on.

e.g. for

```
[Section1]    
length = 5
```

I want to be able to have the result

```
Section1:

length
unit: Meter
range: 0 - 1000
default: 5
Brief: this is my description
```

Please find below my doxygen configuration like requested.
The Input / Output configuration should not be changed.

```
# Doxyfile 1.8.14

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "My Naame"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 
PROJECT_BRIEF          = 
PROJECT_LOGO           = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ../../../../Desktop/Doxygenwx
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
ALLOW_UNICODE_NAMES    = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                = 
TCL_SUBST              = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = 
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 0
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
GROUP_NESTED_COMPOUNDS = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE= NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = NO
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
LAYOUT_FILE            = 
CITE_BIB_FILES         = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
WARN_AS_ERROR          = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = "../../../../Downloads/wxWidgets-3.1.1/samples/#minimal Adapted"
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.idl \
                         *.ddl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.cs \
                         *.d \
                         *.php \
                         *.php4 \
                         *.php5 \
                         *.phtml \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.pyw \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f95 \
                         *.f03 \
                         *.f08 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.tcl \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.qsf
RECURSIVE              = NO
EXCLUDE                = csv.h \
                         "../../../../Downloads/wxWidgets-3.1.1/samples/#minimal Adapted/csv.h"
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS = 
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = YES
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = NO
CLANG_OPTIONS          = 
CLANG_COMPILATION_DATABASE_PATH= 0
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = 
HTML_FOOTER            = 
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = 
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = NO
HTML_DYNAMIC_MENUS     = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     = 
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               = 
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   = 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHG_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = 
MATHJAX_CODEFILE       = 
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHENGINE_URL       = 
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
EXTERNAL_SEARCH_ID     = 
EXTRA_SEARCH_MAPPINGS  = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
LATEX_FOOTER           = 
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = 
LATEX_EXTRA_FILES      = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
LATEX_TIMESTAMP        = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = YES
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 
RTF_SOURCE_CODE        = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_SUBDIR             = 
MAN_LINKS              = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the DOCBOOK output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
DOCBOOK_PROGRAMLISTING = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to external references
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
MSCGEN_PATH            = 
DIA_PATH               = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = NO
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           = 
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 20
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_PATH               = ../../../../Downloads/Software/graphviz-2.38/bin
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
MSCFILE_DIRS           = 
DIAFILE_DIRS           = 
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      = 
PLANTUML_CFG_FILE      = 
PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

Small part of my ini-file (so far its not commented):

```
[sourceFile]
xpChairconfig = .\\Text\\xpChairconfig.txt
wolist = .\\Text\\wolist.txt
chairconfigpath = .\\Text\\chairconfigpath.txt

[filehandling]
useWorkaroundtoOpenFiles = true                     ; Use till files can be opened direct.
```

Comment: Please post a small but complete example including the changes in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile) compared to the default file. Also specify the version of doxygen you are using.

Comment: Making fake C++ code in hope to generate something that documents some .ini file is likely bad idea and result will probably confuse everybody. You can simply write anything about anything in your Doxygen comments (that can include embedded HTML). How you want the results to look like is then up to you.

Comment: And the small source code?

Comment: I've attached the configuration file - including doxygen version - like requested.

Comment: Please add source code also in question and not in comment (mid-air collision ? as comment is gone)

Comment: Sorry for causing inconvinience, I'm not fammiliar with the Forum. I've added a part of my inifile below.

Comment: What is the name of the ini file when offered to doxygen, at the moment I will check with `sime.ini` but especially the extension is important.

Comment: ini files are not supported by doxygen. So you have to convert the file by means of e.g. `INPUT_FILTER` to a format that doxygen understands. Furthermore don't forget to set the `EXTENSION_MAPPING` Other possibility us (as you revered verb include to something like have a `\page` with on it a `\verbinclude <filename>` This will show the `ini` file as it is.

Comment: you are right, Extension is .ini. I've simply called the file config.ini.
Can you please give me an expample with the INPUT_FILTER?
I've no idea how to Approach this Topic. 
And also many thanks for your fast help and your Investigation!

Comment: `INPUT_FILTER` see the doxygen manual. The used implementation of course depends on what you want, which, programming, skills are present, the OS used etc. So best is to try something and when you get stuck ask a new question with the problems encountered.